# Android constraintLayout set layout direction right to left doesn't work

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout, right-to-left

I want the image to always be on the right side of the screen without gaps no matter how long the message is (as shown in the photo). I already set `android:supportsRtl="true"`in the manifest.xml.

[image]

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sent_message"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/time"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="@string/time_stamp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/receiver_photo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/send_image"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I am confused as to why not <ImageView ... app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf=Parent .../>.?   Which would directly implement "right side of the screen without gaps"

Comment: I tried app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf=Parent, but it's still not working